I want to level out my warehouse inventory, across several warehouses by moving inventory around based on inventory levels and avg sales
enter image description hereI have overstock in some DC"s, zero inventory in others, all with a rate of sale. I am trying to use the following formula to tell me where I reduce inventory in overstocked DC's and where I move inventory to understocked DC's but the total on hand inventory does not add up to the total optimal level on the other end of the output: I will post a picture of the formula but I will explain again if I didn't do it well the first time. I want to see, in a column, the amount of inventory I need to move (or keep) in each DC so I level off the total amount of inventory in all DC';s for the item.
I tried this formula =IF(B2 >= AVERAGE($B$2:$B$11), B2 - (B2 - AVERAGE($B$2:$B$11)) * (C2 / AVERAGE($C$2:$C$11)), B2 + (AVERAGE($B$2:$B$11) - B2) * (C2 / AVERAGE($C$2:$C$11))) but the output of the answer didn't total up to the total inventory I start with

add an appropriate image description please
